# Chessbase 13 How to install UCI Engine when menu item is missing?

Tags: chessbase, uci

I have the latest version of Chessbase 13, I have bought a license and activated it online.  For some reason, when I open a new board and go to the `Home` tab I do not have the menu item `Create UIC Engine` button.

[image: Home menu]

As you see I have the choices `Default Kibitzer`, `Add Kibitzer` and `Remove Kibitzer`, but no additional choices while the image in the manual shows there is a small button below `Remove Kibitzer` that opens additional choices.

Have anyone else experienced this?  I have emailed Chessbase support, but they have not seen this before.

Comment: If Chessbase hasn't "seen" it before and unable to help you, I don't think anybody her could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the line Remove Kibitzer, there is "UCI" written in red.  Click on that.

Answer (score 1):

It is the size of the window that matters.  Make it smaller and they will become available (I assume the same is tru for making it larger, but I can't verify as this was my max screen size).

Comment: This works, but suggestion by A passerby is simpler.